# Exporting diagram to visio using java

Tags: java, eclipse

i have made an editor in eclipse in which i have drawn inverted structure chart.How can i export the diagram(chart) drawn in editor to visio using java code?

Answer (score 1):

There are not many libraries that export to Visio, but you could try this one [http://jgrapht.org](http://jgrapht.org/) There should be a class in the library called VisioExporter. I don't know how much support it has but it's worth a try.

Comment: By going into searches i found that SWT OLE Automation is used.But i am not clear hw to use it.Can anybody help me out which tutorials are helpful to understand SWT Ole automation to export editor diagrams to visio??

Comment: Try this http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-ActivexSupportInSwt/index.html